# How to monitor performance of rocket core?

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip

In rocket/RocketCore.scala

There exists performance counter which describes cache misses, load, or store.

How can I see this information after rocket core finishes its running?

Could you give me an example on how to do this?

As far as I know, there's nothing on this guide.